# Using scanf in for loop

Tags: c

Here is my c code:

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        scanf("%d ", &a);

    return 0;
}
```

When I input things like `1 2 3`, it will ask me to input more, and I need to input something not ' '.

However, when I change it to (or other thing not `' '`)

```
scanf("%d !", &a);
```

and input `1 ! 2! 3!`, it will not ask more input.

Comment: I know that will work, but I want to know why "%d " will not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The final space in `scanf("%d ", &a);` instructs `scanf` to consume all white space following the number.  It will keep reading from `stdin` until you type something that is not white space.  Simplify the format this way:

```
scanf("%d", &a);
```

`scanf` will still ignore white space before the numbers.

Conversely, the format `"%d !"` consumes any white space following the number and a single `!`. It stops scanning when it gets this character, or another non space character which it leaves in the input stream.  You cannot tell from the return value whether it matched the `!` or not.

`scanf` is **very** clunky, it is very difficult to use it correctly.  It is often better to read a line of input with `fgets()` and parse that with `sscanf()` or even simpler functions such as `strtol()`, `strspn()` or `strcspn()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%d", &a);
```

This should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `scanf()` consumes `stdin` input as much as its pattern matches. If you pass `"%d"` as the pattern, it will stop reading input after a integer is found. However, if you feed it with `"%dx"` for example, it matches with all integers followed by a character `'x'`.

**More Details:**

Your pattern string could have the following characters:

> - **Whitespace character:** the function will read and ignore any whitespace
>   characters encountered before the next non-whitespace character
>   (whitespace characters include spaces, newline and tab characters --
>   see isspace). A single whitespace in the format string validates any
>   quantity of whitespace characters extracted from the stream (including
>   none).
> - **Non-whitespace character, except format specifier (%):** Any character that is not either a whitespace character (blank, newline or
>   tab) or part of a format specifier (which begin with a % character)
>   causes the function to read the next character from the stream,
>   compare it to this non-whitespace character and if it matches, it is
>   discarded and the function continues with the next character of
>   format. If the character does not match, the function fails, returning
>   and leaving subsequent characters of the stream unread.
> - **Format specifiers:** A sequence formed by an initial percentage sign (%) indicates a format specifier, which is used to specify the type
>   and format of the data to be retrieved from the stream and stored into
>   the locations pointed by the additional arguments.

<sub>Source: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/</sub>

Comment: Note that using `"%dx"` in the example code from the question will in fact accept the input line `1 2 3` because although it fails to match the 'trailing context' (the `x`) for each input number, it does match the number and even reports success.  Try it!